# SQL: How to calculate a Ratio with SUM, JOIN & GROUP?

Tags: mysql, sql, math, statistics

i'm trying to calculate a ratio in SQL that requires figures from two different tables but it keeps spitting out the wrong answer. My query is as follows:

```
SELECT t1.category, ROUND((SUM(t1.cost)/SUM(t2.store_sales)),2) AS ratio
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2;
```

which returns:

```
|     category           |        ratio                  |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| N/A                    |                          0.00 |
| Category 1             |                       1287.71 |
```

but for Category 1 the SUM(t1.cost) = 1,367,502 and the SUM(t2.sales) = 5,819.33, which should give a ratio of 234.99 when you divide the two together. Appreciate any help on where i went wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the group by clause should change

GROUP BY 1 <- you should group by the right columns

Comment: Try adding`, SUM(t1.cost), SUM(t2.store_sales)` to the select list after `AS ratio` to verify that the sums you expect are actually correct, or which one is not.

Comment: maybe that's just for short, but notice you use "t2.store_sales" in the query but "t2.sales" in the description. and better use "GROUP BY t1.category", because maybe "category" is not the first column in "table1" -> I think that's what @ArunGeorge suggests.